# UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor vs. UIBarButtonItem foregroundColor

Tags: ios, swift, uicolor, uiappearance

I was using UIBarButtonItem appearance to set default font and colour.

```
UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor(red: 38/255, green: 110/255, blue: 174/255, alpha: 1)], for: .normal)
```

But because using of this breaks **UIBarButtonItem.Style** (e.g. .done is not bold) I had use **UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor**

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor(red: 38/255, green: 110/255, blue: 174/255, alpha: 1)
UINavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent = false
```

And here comes the problem. Colours are different for these two approaches.

**Colour using UIBarButtonItem appearance**

[image: Colour using UIBarButtonItem appearance]

**Colour using UINavigationBar appearance tintColor**

[image: Colour using UINavigationBar appearance tintColor]

**Question:** How to get correct colour representation?

Comment: when you choose colour picker use "Generic RGB"..hope this will help you and if you will use hex code it will revert back to  sRGB

Comment: @AyushYadav that's it. It's confusing, that colour is displayed correctly before you run the app.
Important is, that colour is used from storyboard and from UINavigationBar appearance. I don't think it's correct behaviour